# What is the antonym of "blank" in "a blank sheet of paper"?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, antonyms

Say, you have a sheet of paper. It is blank. I begin to write on it. It's no longer blank. But then what it is? I have tried the usual sources for antonyms but came up, well, blank.

Comment: Suppose what you write on it is "Intentionally left blank." Is it kosher to call it blank then?

Comment: Interestingly, I think that it is!   "Please turn past the blank page at the start - the intentionally left blank page".  In this context, we are agreeing that it is blank of _content_, even if it isn't blank of marks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A few options:

- full / filled
- marked
- inked
- dirty
- nonblank — oddly in my spellchecker but not in my dictionary
- touched
- unclean

Comment: +1 marked or marked up in this context. Inscribed if you want to be fancy.

Comment: "Unclean! Unclean!"  All joking aside, I don't think that one works here - unless what's on the paper is either plague or a Satanic ritual.

Comment: full/filled would imply that paper is actually full, not that someone had begun to write on it and stopped. I think marked is the best generic term, and inked may be a good term if it was done with ink. Touched could mean its still blank by definition, but that the thought of writing on it occurred.

Answer (score 4):

- If 'blank' means "The entire sheet is unmarked", then  the opposite is "Some part of the sheet is touched", and the antonym is **used** or **marked**
- If 'blank' means "The sheet is unfilled", then  the opposite is "The entire sheet has been marked", and the antonym is **full** or **filled in**

The preferred natural antonym is the first; if you say "that sheet is not blank", the most likely inference is not that it is completely full but that it has at least some marks on it.

Comment: To me, "a full sheet of paper" means one that hasn't been torn/cut in half or something; i.e. one that is the full 8.5x11" (or insert A4 measurements) in size.

Comment: By formal logic the opposite of "No part of the sheet is touched" is "There exists such part of the sheet that is touched". Not the full sheet.

Comment: @chx: yes, the first point is taking the logical negation where a 'sheet' is comprised of all the places on it that can be written on. The second one is where there is one thing, the sheet, and is at one extreme or the other. The seats at a doctors office can be completely empty, completely taken, or somewhere in between, and there is the logical negation of empty which could be taken to be either for some seat or the entire set of seats, i.e. the opposite of empty could be 'at least one seat taken' or it could be 'completely full/no vacancy'. I'll fix my wording for the 2nd.

Answer (score 2):

IF something is written on a blank sheet of paper, I'd call it a used piece of paper.

Answer (score 2):

I like most of @MrHen's answers, but would add "written on" (or "written-on")...that is the one I would be most likely to use colloquially.

Answer (score 1):

When a piece of paper is no longer blank, it becomes something purposeful. It takes shape as a story, list, poem, missive, letter, report, sketch, diagram, doodle, etc.

Comment: So I'd say the only antonym you could say with no other context is that the paper is 'not blank'

Comment: The question asks for an antonym of blank.  None of these words are an antonym of blank.

Answer (score 0):

Well, [Encarta](http://encarta.msn.com/thesaurus_561566915/blank.html) says the antonym for blank is *full* … sort of (I guess) the way the fuel gauge on your car has *empty* and *full* on either spectrum.

Maybe once you start writing you could call it a *partial [whatever you're putting into the sheet of paper]*.

Comment: Why the downvote? This answer is a lot better than many of the others.

Comment: I think downvotes because in the given context, "full" is not the correct word.   A single mark on blank paper does not render it full, but it does render it ... the antonym of blank.

Answer (score 0):

A blank sheet of paper usually means a piece of paper that is clean, ready to be written on. If on the other hand we find a sheet that has something written on it we could say

- it's already been *used* / *written on*
- it's *not clean*
- it's been *scribbled on*
- there's *something on* it

A *clean sheet* can also be called a *blank piece of paper* but if it has been marked or *soiled* in some way we might say

- that's [*scrap paper*](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/scrap-paper)
- it's dirty
- it's not spotless
- it's got smudges/stains/marks on it

If a blank piece of paper is taken to mean that it lacks information of some kind, that it has not been completed, its opposite would be

- it's been *completed*
- it's been *filled*
- it's been [*filled out*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fill_out)
- it's been [*filled in*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/filled+in)

Answer (score -2):

What about *besmirched*?

I personally like *unblank*.

Perhaps *deblanked*?